# Using Springs IoC in this case?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I am curious on the way Spring is able to bind together an application (just in simple terms of course). In a standalone Java application you bootstrap the application with a lookup then Spring instantiates and binds the objects together (DI).

If you for example have a `for` loop where you don't know the number of iterations (user input) would you use the dependency lookup method inside the loop body? And would you implement the BeanFactoryAware interface in this case? Or do you make the object by using `new` keyword?

Just an thing that came to my mind while reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### *"Lets pretend that you need a new instance each time"*

If you have a component A that has a `for` loop where you need a new instance of a "bean" B on each iteration, why not just inject a `B factory` into A and call that within a `for` loop.

It all really comes down to what *makes sense*:

- If you need to create something simple (e.g. a new String) on each iteration, then there is nothing wrong with using a `new` keyword.
- If it is something more complex, where it is best to encapsulate "creation details", it would not do you any good to depend on any particular framework (e.g. `BeanFactoryAware`). Just use a builder/factory, which can either be another bean that would be injected, or can be called statically.

---

*Less magic more clarity*

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly the answer could be: Spring beans are singletons by default.

So in most cases you would never need to lookup one inside the for loop - you'll use the instance looked up just before your loop.

Also you're probably trying to think about Spring beans as JavaBeans that you create to populate with data. You could read this link to see the difference: http://www.shaunabram.com/beans-vs-pojos/

Spring beans are more like JavaEE Enterprise Beans, you don't create them - you just use them.

Comment: Lets pretend that you need a new instance each time.

Comment: It's the same as with JavaEE session beans. You can require a new instance of a Stateful Session Bean on each iteration, but there's just not much use for that.